# Zend Framework 2 Htaccess

Tags: zend-framework2

Hello guys i have problem in ZF2 with htaccess.

I create vhost and all work good. when i call

**my-vhost.localhost** all work good but when i add some uri segment like /index.php or /1234
I get 404.

I edit .htaccess in public dir and put

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Bur again i have 404. Any idea how i can i slow this?

My full .htaccess is :

```
RewriteEngine On

# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

VHOST

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory /var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Who think problem is routing check my route mod.

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
        ),
    ),

    // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/album[/][:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: You have idea about ZF2 routings?

Comment: This is not routing this is HTACCESS READ ALBUM TUTORIAL

Comment: Please post your vhost file also if you can. It may be something like AllowOverride is set to none (in which case the .htaccess is never executed) or you're pointing to the wrong folder?

Comment: The section of your vhost file provided works fine. Perhaps as @noobie-php suggested it might be a routing issue. Or module config?

Answer (score 2):

The contents of the shipped .htaccess file are as follows;

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

It differs very slightly from your copy, I have tried your .htaccess file on a working example and it appears fine.

Is the 404 you are getting a generic "server looking" 404 or is it a ZF2 themed page?

Might be a silly suggestion but have you tried http://my-vhost.localhost/public or http://my-vhost.localhost/public/album  ???

As far as I know you shouldnt need to call .php files directly

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure it is too late to answer this question, as Finbarr suggest to try with 
 http://my-vhost.localhost/public or http://my-vhost.localhost/public/album.

I had also the same problem everytime I type  www.zf2-tutorial.loc  it always was redirected to xampp main page.

Finally i read the comments froom Finbarr i changed to

```
http://www.zf2-tutorial.loc/zf2-tutorial/public/
```

after that  the webspage: Welcome to Zend Framework 2 was loaded.

```
#the virtual host:
```

NameVirtualHost *:80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
<DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/zf2-tutorial/public"
ServerName  www.zf2-tutorial.loc zf2-tutorial.loc
ServerAlias zf2-tutorial.loc
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/zf2-tutorial/public">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

in the host  I made several combinations  trying to find out which one was correct.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   www.zf2-tutorial.loc  zf2-tutorial.loc
127.0.0.1   www.zf2-tutorial.loc  zf2-tutorial.loc localhost
127.0.0.1   www.zf2-tutorial.loc  localhost
127.0.0.1   www.zf2-tutorial.loc
127.0.0.1   zf2-tutorial.loc localhost
127.0.0.1   zf2-tutorial.loc
```

the apache (httpd conf)  has this settings some people suggest to delete he hash tag but I didn't work for me so left it as i found it:

```
# Virtual hosts
# Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Also in the same file  (httpd conf) I change the AllowOverride None to AllowOverride FileInfo  as follows:

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride FileInfo
Require all denied
</Directory>
```

re started the xampp and it was displayed the congratulations web page.