# How to properly configure routes

Tags: php, zend-framework2

When I try to acces to `127.0.0.1/projectName/compte` or to `127.0.0.1/projectName/public/compte` or to `127.0.0.1/compte` via this configuration:

```
       'compte' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/compte[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Compte',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

I get a 404 Not Found error. But, when I try to access to `127.0.0.1/projectName/public` it works for an another page.

What's wrong please ?

Any brilliant idea, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zend Framework 2 Htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341334/zend-framework-2-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

If `127.0.0.1/projectName/public/index.php/compte` works then its the `mod_rewrite` issue.

Please enable the apache module with `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

and

restart apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`

Let us know the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS with URL Rewrite Module Module, import the following lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,L]
```

Similar : [Zend Framework 2 Htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341334/zend-framework-2-htaccess) and [Zend Framework 2 .htaccess mamp pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827304/zend-framework-2-htaccess-mamp-pro).

See more (fr) : [FR - User-guide](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2-documentation/blob/master/docs/languages/fr/user-guide/skeleton-application.rst)